# Knockout Access change event on select function

Tags: javascript, events, select, knockout.js, onchange

I am trying to pass the event to my function on a select.

This is from the knockout documentation:

```
<div data-bind="event: { mouseover: function(data, event) { myFunction('param1', 'param2', data, event) } }">
    Mouse over me
</div>
```

I have tried it like this:

```
<select name="ans" data-bind="options: $root.Answers,optionsValue: 'Answer',value: Answer(),event:{change: function(event){ $root.selectAnswer($data,$index,$element.name,event)}}"></select>
```

function

```
self.selectAnswer = function (data,index,type,event)
{     
     if (event.originalEvent)
     {
      ...
     }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the event I am getting is actually $data and not the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes sense, right. Compare the docs you quote:

```
mouseover: function(data, event) { myFunction
```

with your version:

```
event: { change: function(event) { $root.se
```

The first argument of the handler will receive the `$data`, which goes into your `event` named argument. You should change your version to:

```
event: { change: function(data, event) { $root.se
```

And the `event` will actually contain the `event`.